# Combining two SQL results (with varying columns) into one JSON object

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that dynamically builds a SELECT statement in SQL, and outputs as per the example below (note there can be as many as 50 select statements, each unique per email);

| Email | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc@googlemail.com | 96 | Male |

| Email | Age | AddressLine1 | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| def@googlemail.com | 36 | 1 Laneview Way | England |

I would like to combine the output of the two (or more) queries, into one JSON object, if possible, so it would output like below;

```
[
   {
      "Email":"abc@googlemail.com",
      "Age":"96",
      "Gender":"Male"
   },
   {
      "Email":"def@googlemail.com",
      "Age":"36",
      "AddressLine1":"1 Laneview Way",
      "Country":"England"
   }
]
```

My current attempt in SQL is as follows;

```
SELECT User_Alias = JSON_QUERY(query1.json_result), User_Alias2 = JSON_QUERY(query2.json_result) FROM
(
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       Gender
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email = 'abc@googlemail.com'
FOR JSON PATH
) AS query1 (json_result)
,(
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       AddressLine1,
       Country
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email = 'def@googlemail.com'
FOR JSON PATH
) AS query2 (json_result)
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Answer (score 0):

It was written in two ways with two values and one value

Two values(User_Alias,User_Alias2)

```
select User_Alias = (
    SELECT Email,
            Age,
            Gender
    FROM tableAbc
    WHERE Email = 'abc@googlemail.com'
    FOR JSON PATH

),User_Alias2 = 
(
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       AddressLine1,
       Country
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email = 'def@googlemail.com'
FOR JSON PATH
) 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

one values

```
select CONCAT( (
    SELECT Email,
            Age,
            Gender
    FROM tableAbc
    WHERE Email = 'abc@googlemail.com'
    FOR JSON PATH

),
(
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       AddressLine1,
       Country
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email = 'def@googlemail.com'
FOR JSON PATH
) )
```

dbfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/tZaEDwIE

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you should actually be doing is just using `NULL` for the columns you don't want to show. Any null columns are simply not serialized into the JSON at all, unless you specify `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES`.

```sql
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       Gender,
       AddressLine1,
       Country
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email IN ('abc@googlemail.com', 'def@googlemail.com')
FOR JSON PATH;
```

This assumes those columns are already null for those rows. If they are not then you need some `CASE` expressions

```sql
SELECT Email,
       Age,
       Gender = CASE WHEN Email = 'abc@googlemail.com' THEN Gender END,
       AddressLine1 = CASE WHEN Email = 'def@googlemail.com' THEN AddressLine1 END,
       Country = CASE WHEN Email = 'def@googlemail.com' THEN Country END
FROM tableAbc
WHERE Email IN ('abc@googlemail.com', 'def@googlemail.com')
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/gMU9XMIc)